# Excel sumif or sumifs with concatenated values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have problem in collating the results from table. Following is the data i have . Here i need to combine the count for test names and test names(failed). i.e., I need to take and collate Blue and Blue(Failed). However this shouldn't include "Blue ocean" entities.

[image: original data]

Here is what is expect :

[image: expected]

I tried using sumif, sumifs and vlookup. However i couldn't achieve what i wanted . Is there a ways to have concatenation in the criteria value of this function like "cell value containing blue" & "(failed)"

Sumif

```
=SUMIF(A:A,E3&"*",B:B)
```

Sumifs

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,E3,A:A,E3 & "*")
```

when i tried to use the concatenation in sumifs it returns 0

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,C60,A:A,TRIM(C60)&"(failed)")
```

Your inputs much appreciate.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe add two SUMIFs?

Comment: @SJR thank you for such a simple solution .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((E2=$A$2:$A$10)+(E2&"(failed)"=$A$2:$A$10))*$B$2:$B$10)
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Formula can be a little shortened:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((E2&{"";"(failed)"}=$A$2:$A$10))*$B$2:$B$10)
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing  sumproduct .  =SUMPRODUCT(((E3=A3:A12)+(TRIM(E3)&"(failed) "=A3:A12))*B3:B12) looks like i can have ranges like A:A and B:B

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT` can be a lifesave, but be aware that isn't likely to beat two added `SUMIF` functions performance-wise. Whole columns as a reference in `SUMPRODUCT` is killing @deepakguna.

Comment: @deepakguna Yes, JvdV is right, with SUMPRODUCT you have to be careful and see how much data you have - if you feel your computer is starting to slow down, it's worth looking at other functions. In the example, I forgot to specify absolute references, corrected.